# Scroll automatically a part of the page in javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, chat

I have a project that has a chat app that looks like this:

[chat app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uYb.jpg)

as you can see the scroll bar is not in the window, it is at the chat section,
what I want to do is to scroll automatically down of the chat section.
I try doing this:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

but that doesn´t work, is there another way to only scroll down only the chat section?

Comment: Is your chat on the bottom of the page? Also, are you trying to scroll the page or the chat window?

Comment: no, is not, and I'am trying to scroll down only the chat window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see on the screenshot, you need to scroll the chat section, not the whole window.

```
const chatContainer = document.querySelector("#chat-container");

chatContainer.scrollTo(0, chatContainer.scrollHeight)
```

Comment: I was thinking that the scrollTo was only with window, but document.querySelector change everything